# “init terminating in do_boot” Windows 10 Rabbit MQ fails to start

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

I tried to install `Rabbit MQ` and an error has occurred when I was running `rabbitmq-server`.

Follows the error:

[image]

My installing environment was `erl 8.1` and r`abbitmq-server-windows-3.6.6`. The operating system was `Windows 10(64x)`.

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{badarg,[{io,format,[<0.53.0>,"~n~nBOOT FAILED~n===========~n~nError description:~n   ~p~n~nLog files (may contain more information):~n   ~s~n   ~s~n~n",[{could_not_start,rabbit,{badarg,[{io,format,[<0.135.0>,"~n              ~s ~s. ~s~n  ##  ##      ~s~n  ##  ##~n  ##########  Logs: ~s~n  ######  ##        ~s~n  ##########~n              Starting broker...~n",["RabbitMQ","3.6.6","Copyright (C) 2007-2016 Pivotal Software, Inc.","Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/",[67,58,47,85,115,101,114,115,47,27494,24198,36229,47,65,112,112,68,97,116,97,47,82,111,97,109,105,110,103,47,82,97,98,98,105,116,77,81,47,108,111,103,47,82,65,66,66,73,84,126,49,46,76,79,71],[67,58,47,85,115,101,114,115,47,27494,24198,36229,47,65,112,112,68,97,116,97,47,82,111,97,109,105,110,103,47,82,97,98,98,105,116,77,81,47,108,111,103,47,82,65,66,66,73,84,126,50,46,76,79,71]]],[]},{rabbit,start,2,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,683}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,273}]}]}},[67,58,47,85,115,101,114,115,47,27494,24198,36229,47,65,112,112,68,97,116,97,47,82,111,97,109,105,110,103,47,82,97,98,98,105,116,77,81,47,108,111,103,47,82,65,66,66,73,84,126,49,46,76,79,71],[67,58,47,85,115,101,114,115,47,27494,24198,36229,47,65,112,112,68,97,116,97,47,82,111,97,109,105,110,103,47,82,97,98,98,105,116,77,81,47,108,111,103,47,82,65,66,66,73,84,126,50,46,76,79,71]]],[]},{rabbit,log_boot_error_and_exit,3,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,742}]},{rabbit,start_it,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,407}]},{init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1076}]},{init,do_boot,3,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,784}]}]}}
```

`init` terminating in `do_boot ()`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.And I solved this problem by below:

1. Check all the paths of RabbitMQ and Erlang have no non-ASCII characters;
2. Make sure all the File Locations of RabbitMQ have no non-ASCII characters by setting `RABBITMQ_BASE` environment variable as [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html) say:

   > RABBITMQ_BASE This base directory contains sub-directories for the RabbitMQ server's database and log files. Alternatively, set RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE and RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE individually.

According to `rabbitmq-env.bat`:
`REM Make sure $RABBITMQ_BASE contains no non-ASCII characters.`

Hope this answer will help you.